# How do you perform a reactor build in Maven3 without a root project?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

How does one perform an ad-hoc reactor build over multiple maven projects without a root project?

This used to be possible in maven2 by invoking the mvn command with the '-r' option which would search recursively from the working directory for projects and organize them in the reactor to build in the correct order even if the projects did not share a common parent pom.xml. Optionally one could specifically include or exclude certain projects using maven.reactor.includes and maven.reactor.excludes option.

I realize that the legacy reactor mode was removed from maven3 but I can't figure out how to achieve this functionality using the 'make-like' reactor mode.

Comment: Maybe this is just NOT aligned with Maven philosophy any longer?

Comment: Seems weird to remove something useful without a replacement.

Comment: Maybe you should put a pom.xml in your module1 project (this will be the parent pom) and a pom_module1.xml in your module1 project (this will be the module1 pom). you can refer the pom_module1.xml in your first module tag of pom.xml. the others modules could by referenced by ../module2 and so on in the module tag of pom.xml in the module1 project.

This is what you need?

Comment: We had this issue too, so we simply placed a pom consisting of nothing but module elements. Each refers to a subdirectory containing the maven module. We are working on a script to automate generating such pom from a single maven project (each dependency which has SCM tag will be checked out as a module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Maven 2"-style reactor feature has been removed following [this discussion](http://markmail.org/thread/7ztzhcg62yjcqmpb) on the mailing list.  The relevant JIRA issue is [MNG-4260](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4260).

As mentioned in the comments above, it's best to create a top-level pom with a `<modules>` section that lists the directories containing projects. (If you don't always build all of your projects at the same time, you can put separate `modules` sections in profiles).

Comment: Accepting this because it is not possible to preform a build as described in my question with maven3 as the links in this answer point out. It is honestly a shame though "rootless" reactor builds was a pretty cool but not widely discussed feature(bug?) of Maven2