# Resolving dependencies ad-hoc in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have an multi-module project in maven, and when I run normal goals on it, everything works fine. For testing, I have an module mytest, and this module is run fine when I run mvn package in the parent directory.

But for not compiling and running everything everytime, I would prefer to run the tests standalone, and to take the packaged files as the dependencies. But if I try to do so using mvn test -Dtest=simpleTest in the test-submodule-directory, the tests are not run, because it can't find the dependencies. After a mvn install in the parent-directory, it finds them, but uses the artifacts from the repository - a behaviour I do not want, because I have to run install everytime. And if I try to run the tests from the parent directory with mvn test -Dtest=simpleTest, it does not find the tests in the other modules, and stops, or, if I add an project-list with -pl test, it just does not find the dependencies again.

Is there any way to run a maven test in a specific submodule, that has dependencies for other submodules, without installing the submodules to the local repository? It would be possible to archieve this by building the comand-line-call for the test onself, but that seems very time-consuming.

/EDIT:

To describe the problem more exactly, I'll add source of a minimal project.

There is a parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimalproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>minimalproject</name>

    <modules>
        <module>datamodule</module>
        <module>testmodule</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

a Pom for the module that needs to be tested (in a real-world project, there would be more similiar modules):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>datamodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>datamodule</name>
</project>
```

and a Pom for the modules that tests:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>testmodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>testmodule</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>datamodule</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

There are now two classes, one in datamodule/src/main/java:

```
public class Thing{
    int i = 5;
}
```

and one in testmodule/src/test/java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class MyTest{

    @Test
    public void testThing(){
        Thing t = new Thing();
        Assert.assertEquals(5, t.i);
    }
}
```

When I now run `mvn package` in the parent folder, everything works fine. But if I run `mvn test` in the testmodule folder, it crashes because it can't resolve the dependency to the datamodule. If I run `mvn install` in the parent folder before, it works - but takes the old installed version.

What I want is the ability to run the integration-test in the testmodule, without calling other tests or invoking the build-process of other parts. Is there any possibility to do so?

/EDIT2:

I found out when googling the issue, that one could have done that in maven 2 with the reactor plugin: [Build single module from multimodule pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612854/build-single-module-from-multimodule-pom) . Anyways, this plugin is not used anymore (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/VOTE-Retire-Maven-Reactor-Plugin-td5789172.html). In fact, like proposed in the first answer, people say one could use profiles to do this: [How do you perform a reactor build in Maven3 without a root project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751561/how-do-you-perform-a-reactor-build-in-maven3-without-a-root-project)

But, when adding a profile like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>onlyRunTests</id>
        <modules>
            <module>testmodule</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And runnning it with mvn test -P onlyRunTests, still everything which comes before testing the testmodule (so compiling and running the datamodule) is executed. Unfortunately, this is the behaviour not wanted - I want to call integration tests, not the unit tests from the other modules. So is there any way to do so?

/EDIT 3:
There were two other promising ways to avoid this Problem: building with --pl e.g. --pl testmodule --also-make-dependencies. This does not work either, it does not build the dependencies.
The other way would be defining a path (with systemPath) of the depencies. This does not work, as it only works with absolute paths, and this would make the pom unexecutable under all other systems.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your inter module dependencies, but without a full example or best the project it's hard to guess what's really wrong...And of course usually your build must work with `mvn clean package` without previous `mvn install`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've added code for a minimal version of the problem, so the issue is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your build is (based on the example pom files) not a multi-module build cause if you have a multi-module build all your childs need to have a parent which is *not* the case. In your case you are having an aggregator which is not what you need.

The test module should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>minimalproject</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>testmodule</artifactId>

    <name>testmodule</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>datamodule</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and your datamodule should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>minimalproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>minimalproject</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>datamodule</artifactId>

    <name>datamodule</name>
</project>
```

Now if you look at the root and try `mvn clean package` you should see that the testmodule is build after the datamodule. This is needed as you already determined to let Maven calculate the build order of the artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this all works right, so I am able to build everything when I do it in the parent folder. But is there any possibility to build only one project, with the project resolving its dependencies in the same module? So I don't want to call install in every module, but I want to run test in the integration-test module, to only start the testing of the other modules. Is there any possibility to do so?